# Prove that $\mathbb{P}( \sum_{k=1}^{X_0+1} X_k = 0) = $exp$ $ {$-2\lambda +\lambda e^{-\lambda}$ }

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Prove that $\mathbb{P}( \sum_{k=1}^{X_0+1} X_k= 0) = exp $ {$-2\lambda +\lambda e^{-\lambda}$ }
with $\lambda_0 = \lambda_1 = ... =: \lambda > 0$ and $ \lambda_n > 0$ for all $n \in \mathbb{N_0} ,(X_k)_{k \in \mathbb{N_0}} $ independent variables with $X_n \sim $Poi$ ( \lambda_n)$

I'm totally struggling with this exercies I would very appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: sum... of what?

Comment: thank you I edited the question

Comment: Once you split it conditionally to the value of $X_0$ you get an easy formula

Comment: Could you eventually help me a bit more with the solution? I can't go further with the proof

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Being the $X_k$ i.i.d. and Poisson you have that

$$
\begin{align*}
\Pr \left[\sum_{k=1}^{X_0+1}X_k=0\right]&=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\Pr \left[\sum_{k\geqslant 1}^{n+1}X_k=0\middle|X_0=n\right]\Pr [X_0=n]\\
&=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\Pr \left[\sum_{k= 1}^{n+1}X_k=0\right]\Pr [X_0=n]\\
&=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\Pr \left[\bigcap_{k=1}^{n+1}\{X_k=0\}\right]\Pr [X_0=n]\\
&=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}(\Pr [X_0=0])^{n+1}\Pr [X_0=n]\\
&=\sum_{n\geqslant 0}(e^{-\lambda })^{n+1}\frac{\lambda ^{n}}{n!}e^{-\lambda }\\
&=e^{-2\lambda }\sum_{n\geqslant 0}\frac{(\lambda e^{-\lambda })^n}{n!}\\
&=e^{\lambda e^{-\lambda }-2\lambda }
\end{align*}
$$
∎